# raspberry pi samba share not visible in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: samba, raspberrypi

I set up a samba share using a raspberry pi 1 Model B+ running the latest raspbian. Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't show any shared folders from the raspi while Ubuntu 16.04 shows the shared folders.

Searching the web, I found that setting "client max protocol" and "client min protocol" helped others to solve the issue, however, doesn't solve my problem.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Messing around with it, Ubuntu 18.04 isable to browse the shared folders now. I added "client max protocol = NT1" right under the workgroup = WORKGROUP line  at /etc/samba/smb.conf. Still, I would prefer if host and share negotiated to use smb2 or smb3. Any ideas why this is not happening?

Answer (score 0):

And what happens when you access the raspberry directley with it's mDNS qualified host name ( its host name with a .local attached at the end )? Like this from a terminal:

```
nautilus smb://raspberry.local
```

Make sure you have avahi installed on the pi:

```
sudo apt install avahi-daemon
```

You can then bookmark it in nautilus or we can make a avahi service registration file for samba so that it shows up in nautilus under "Other Locations":

Create a file on the pi at /etc/avahi/services/samba.service.
Add this to file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone='no'?>
<!DOCTYPE service-group SYSTEM "avahi-service.dtd">
<service-group>
   <name replace-wildcards="yes">%h SMB</name> ## Display Name
   <service>
       <type>_smb._tcp</type>
       <port>445</port>
   </service>
</service-group>
```

Then under "Other Locations" in nautilus it will show up as **raspberry SMB**

Either way the two systems will talk to each other using smb3